# Problemas al guardar un proyecto en onedrive

Tags: c#

Esto es lo que me aparece cuando intento abrir un proyecto
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y no se porque me pasa nunca me había pasado y llevo unos días que me pasa a cada rato yo le doy a guardar todo y cierro el visual y luego al día siguiente me pone esto, no se si sera que los proyectos los guardo en una carpeta que cree yo y no es del visual pero sino ya me hubiese salido el error.
ojalá que me puedan contestar muchas gracias.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Este es el output y el error que no es nada mas de la dirección de el proyecto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parece que el archivo sln se te ha da dañado o que basicamente hay uno o mas proyectos que no puede cargar por la ruta de acceso o porque ya no existen, puedes editarlo con el block de notas y eliminar las referencias a los proyectos que no existan.

Tambien, puedes crear una solucion en blanco y luego en la ventana de explorador de soluciones añadir el proyecto ya creado previamente a la nueva solucion.

Otra cosa que puedes hacer tambien, es darnos mas informacion y enviar una captura de la pantalla de output o de salida en la cual se detallara algo mas del error

Un saludo

EDITO:
Ahora que envias la salida, el problema es por el OneDrive, que o bien no te accede o no tiene permisos de escritura.
Prueba a crear un proyecto nuevo cambiando la ruta de acceso a ver si arreglas.

[image: Archivo, Nuevo Proyecto y Fijate en la ruta que has de cambiar por otra diferente]

Comment: muchas gracias por contestar. Lo de la ruta de acceso se podría arreglar cambiando donde guardo los proyectos. La verdad es que no se como hacer lo que me has dicho del block de notas ni lo de la solución en blanco, tengo 15 años y casi se puede decir que he empezado con esto de la programación y no se como funciona la mitad de las cosas de que tiene visual studios.

Comment: Hola, al ver la ruta estás apuntando a OneDrive, podría ser que al sincronizar este archivo se corrompa y por eso no te deje abrirlo, estoy suponiendo. Si creas un proyecto nuevo en el escritorio te da el mismo error?? Saludos

Comment: @SebastiánMiranda muchas gracias, ya lo guardo en una carpeta que no este con oneDrive y me funciona.

Comment: @CesarBa muchísimas gracias así si que me funciona